# MySQL Update with field being a concatenated string

Tags: php, mysql

```
function updateUser($userData, $statsID) {
    $fields = '';
    $config = 0;

    while(list($key,$val)= each($userData)) {

      if($config++ != 0){
        $fields .= ' , ';
      }
      $col = $key;
      $val = $val;
      $fields .= "$col='$val'";
    }
    //echo $fields;
    global $dbhandle;
    $query = mysqli_query($dbhandle, "UPDATE data SET $fields WHERE statsID = '$statsID'");
```

echo var_export($query); <--returns NULL

In this code, I pass in an array as noted below:

```
$sendData = array('name'=>$name,'race'=>$race,'rank'=>$rank,'highestRank'=>$highestRank,'commander'=>$commander,'atkSld'=>$atkSld,'atkMerc'=>$atkMerc,'defSld'=>$defSld,'defMerc'=>$defMerc,'untSld'=>$untSld,'untMerc'=>$untMerc,'spies'=>$spies,'sentries'=>$sentries,'morale'=>$morale,'tff'=>$tff,'strike'=>$strike,'strikeRank'=>$strikeRank,'defense'=>$defense,'defenseRank'=>$defenseRank,'spy'=>$spy, 'spyRank'=>$spyRank, 'sentry'=>$sentry, 'sentryRank'=>$sentryRank, 'fort'=>$fort,'siege'=>$siege,'economy'=>$economy,'tech'=>$tech,'conscription'=>$conscription,'gold'=>$gold,'tbg'=>$tbg,'gameTurns'=>$gameTurns,'covertLvl'=>$covertLvl);
```

I have confirmed all the data is set and correct. The statsID passes in correctly and when I echo field, it gives me exactly what is required to fulfill my query and in the correct format (key='value' , key ='value' , key ='value etc)

EDIT: Problem solved, I have updated my code to reflect the solution. For some reason I had to call global $dbhandle prior to the query string. If someone could tell me why that would be great!

Comment: To troubleshoot, do a `var_export()` on your query string and include it in your question.

Comment: echo the query string, copy it and run it directly on the DB or check error log